# How to add custom headers to AWS S3 .NET SDK GetObjectRequest?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, sdk, http-headers

How can I add custom headers to the GetObjectRequest using the .NET SDK? If the SDK does not allow this functionality, why does the .NET SDK not implemented this functionality?

Is it the AWS S3 standard not allowing it? If so, what is the rationale behind (not a good practice)?

If it is not the AWS S3 standard, why does it not implement?

Thanks.

Comment: What possible custom headers do you need to add to a `GET` request for an object, and what effect do you anticipate they would have?

Comment: Custom information for diagnosis purpose - e.g. Initiator ID, User session information or a transaction ID so that the transaction flow can be correlated in the logging information.